# Select Next value that meets a criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select cell by cell in column "A" which are filled by colour red(colour code=3). Each time a button is clicked selection should move to next cell which is filled in red (same column).

My Code so far:

```
Sub FindNext()
    Dim c As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B500")
        Set c = .Find(Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Do
                c.Select
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: I have posted below the code I have done so far

Comment: Note: Never use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. This line just hides *all* error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. Therefore you cannot fix them. Read [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling) to learn how do implement error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the code for the red color is 255. If you mean another code, just change in the code below.

With a simple for loop you can get the next Red cell in the column:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim Srow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Srow = Selection.Row

For i = Srow +1 To 500 'Replace 500 by Lastrow if your last cell has a value inside
    If Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = 255 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It should be `For i = Srow To LastRow` I think?

Comment: I wrote that but then I noticed that OP wrote 500 for the last row, and that I don t know whether there are values everywhere or not. If he only has colors my 'Lastrow' doesn t work and I'd need to adjust it

Comment: Ah nevermind, just was wondering why you determined the last row and then didn't use it.

Comment: Thanks for replies, It moves to the next red cell if the active cell is not red. Great.

Comment: I changed the Starting cell of the loop to the one after the current selection. With this it should select the next red cell.

Comment: @SajW please accept the answer if it works, that s how we thank here ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
Dim r As Range
If Intersect(ActiveCell, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then [A1].Select
With Application.FindFormat
    .clear
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End With
Set r = Columns("A").Find("", ActiveCell, searchformat:=True)
If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Select
End Sub
```

Another working solution